# Why we don't have to add try-catch to a RuntimeException?

Tags: java, exception

I want to ask why we don't have to add try-catch block to a `RuntimeException` while we should do that with other exceptions?

I mean like :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Edit : 
when I say : `throw new RuntimeException();` it is so clear that there is an exception will happen ,so why the compiler doesn't forbid that ?

Comment: Note that `RuntimeExceptions` are usually thrown when a programming / code logic error has occurred. The solution is usually just bugfixing the code. You should generally not catch them.

Comment: Really? I believe that one of best practice is to convert checked exception to unchecked exception than catch all of them at one place to display to user?

Comment: @vodkhang what I am trying to say is why the compiler doesn't forbid a code when it is clear that there is a RuntimeException will happen.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's because it's an **unchecked** exception. It doesn't need to be explicitly declared or catched. Also see the [Java tutorial on the subject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html).

In general, you should only throw a `RuntimeException` (preferably one of its ["Direct Known Subclasses"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) listed in the javadoc) to signal that the caller is doing it wrong. E.g. when the caller incorrectly passes a `null` argument (then throw [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)), or an illegal argument (then throw [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)), or when the caller invokes the method at the wrong moment/state (then throw [`IllegalStateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html)), etcetera. The caller is supposed to fix their code to avoid that. E.g. checking beforehand if the argument is not null, or if the argument is in correct format/syntax, or ensuring that the method is called at the right moment.

If there is a specific situation which should throw a runtime exception and you can't use one of its specific subclasses, then you are supposed to extend it and document it properly in the new exception's javadoc and in the calling method, e.g. `ConfigurationException extends RuntimeException` for the case that the calling code hasn't configured the application/API properly before use. This should signal the enduser (the other developer) sufficiently to take action accordingly.

In a nutshell:

- [`RuntimeExceptions`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) should identify programmatically recoverable problems which are caused by faults in code flow or configuration under control of code developer (read: developer's faults).
- Checked [`Exceptions`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html) should identify programmatically recoverable problems which are caused by unexpected conditions outside control of code developer (e.g. database down, file I/O error, wrong enduser input, etc).
- [`Errors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Error.html) should identify programmatically unrecoverable problems outside control of code developer (e.g. out of memory, exception inside an initializer, etc).

Comment: but when I say : "throw new RuntimeException();" it is so clear that there is an exception will happen ,so why the compiler doesn't forbid that ?

Comment: There is nothing morally wrong with an exception. Unchecked exceptions are intentionally not checked. Hence the name unchecked.

Comment: @M.H no it is not clear. An example is the method List.add(), a normal implementation of list, like arraylist will never throw an UnsupportedOperationException, so there is no need for it to be in the exception signature. The method Collections.asUnmodifyableList() will return a List which will throw an UnsupportedOperationException on calls to List.add. The implementation of List.add consists only of throw new UnsupportedOperationException. With only having an object of type List you can't see if the exception will be thrown and a normal list should never throw it.

Comment: @josefx yes it is not clear in most cases , but is there any ambiguity when you say "throw new RuntimeException();" ??

Comment: @M.H for the code which calls the function there is. Writing throw new UnsupportedOperationException() is the same, you know it will be thrown but does the calling code need to know? The exception signature is for the calling code and it should not have to expect that a List will throw this exception, even if it is clear for the line in UnmodifyableList.add() that there will be an exception thrown. Also the public static void main(String...) method is just a normal java function for the compiler, it can be called by other functions and may throw exceptions like any other function.

Answer (score 3):

Lets argue this way. What if NullPointerException was designed to be a compile time exception? Had it been done so, the compiler had to strictly check whether a variable is null or not. There is no way that this can be done.

```
public void dummyMethod(Object obj){

}
```

Here there is no way for the compiler to check whether the obj can be null or not. However, there has to be some error/exception has to be thrown when you have a null pointer scenario.

Comment: Do you claim that it would introduce some fundamental constraint if NullPointerException was a checked exception? I don't get the example you provide? It might make perfect sense for the method to accept obj == null in some implementations.

Comment: I just wanted you to think in terms of design aspect. Its perfectly logical to have both checked and unchecked. Now, in order for the compiler to check these rules, you will have to set the 'types' of them of which RuntimeException is one and NullPointerException is a type of it. And the answer to your question is yes, its a prob when NPE is made checked. The example I have provided is to tell that the Object obj passed to the method can be and cannot be null and that this method has no idea about it. A compiler can never check such instances.

Answer (score 2):

`RuntimeException`, `Error` and their subclasses are specifically not compile-time checked - they are not part of the formal contract of the method.

See Chapter 11 in the JLS, Exceptions, in particular 11.2, Compile-time checking of Exceptions.

- [JLS, Ch. 11, Exceptions.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html)

Answer (score 2):

Per language specification, *unchecked exceptions* are **not checked at compile-time** which means that the compiler does not require methods to catch or to specify (with a `throws`) them. Classes belonging to this category are detailed in the section [11.2 Compile-Time Checking of Exceptions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html#44121) of the JLS:

> **The *unchecked exceptions classes* are the class `RuntimeException`  and its subclasses, and the class `Error` and its subclasses**. All other exception classes are *checked exception classes*. The Java API defines a number of exception classes, both checked and unchecked. Additional exception classes, both checked and unchecked, may be declared by programmers. See [§11.5](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/exceptions.doc.html#44278) for a description of the exception class hierarchy and some of the exception classes defined by the Java API and Java virtual machine.

So because a `RuntimeException` in a unchecked exception, the compiler doesn't force you to handle it. If you want to force the caller of a piece of code to handle an exception, use a checked exception (the subclasses of `Exception` other than `RuntimeException` are all checked exception classes).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the answers on this forum have been talking about the Exception hierarchy and the Java compiler not catching them but I would try to answer this more from the design perspective and why perhaps things were designed like this.

Basically when you call a function(or write some code) an exception can be thrown out of it based on three different situations:

1. **Based on an unavoidable condition** like unavailability of network or some expected file missing on the file system.
2. **Based on an avoidable but known condition** like `Integer.parseInt(String)` can throw `NumberFormatException` if the caller passes a unconvertible string like `"Hello"`, but the caller may ensure proper validations in place before passing in any string to the function and completely do away with the possibility of generating the exception. A common use case could be validating the form field `age` on a web page before passing it to deeper layers that make the conversion.
3. **An unknown or unexpected condition** Any time some line of code can throw an exception in your code because there was some mistake that you did and didn't observe the error condition until it blasted off in production, generally happens with `NullPointer Reference`, `IndexOutOfBounds` etc, which if observed would possibly fall in category 2.

Exceptions of category 1 are generally designed as `Checked Exceptions` because it needs to enforce the check for unavoidable error conditions, and to enforce their fallbacks. For examples IOException is checked exception, because in case you are opening a file, there can be a lot many things that may go wrong(like file may be deleted, permissions etc.)and pre validating all of them can be very cumbersome.

Exceptions of the 2nd type are generally modeled as `Unchecked Exceptions` because you might have your pre validation in place and it might be irritating to be forced to use try and catch for situations that you have already have taken care of.

Exceptions of the 3rd type need not be even worried about generally because you cannot put error handling in each and every statement of application code that can unexpectedly come up. But sometimes you can place a global handler, somewhere quite up in the call stack from where almost all the application code gets executed and handle it in a generic manner so that your application does not crash due to an unexpected error.

For example, if you're running a web application you can configure your Servlet Container to send out a generic `500 Internal Server Error` for any unhandled error in your application. Or, if you're running a standalone Java application you can keep the contents of your `main method` in a `try catch` block to prevent crashing the application.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's not forbidden to throw runtime exceptions and you don't have to declare runtime exceptions. Your program is a valid Java program so the compiler has no reason to complain.

Answer (score 1):

Basically an uncaught exception is just shorthand for displaying a message and terminating the application.

Why would you need to do that? In some cases you can detect that something has gone wrong, some file didn't load, an api is missing, some data is for some reason corrupted, or one of a million other things is wrong. If you don't throw an exception the application may simply crash at another point, or in the worst case, keep running while the error escalates, making it much harder to debug.

It's important to understand that one throws an exception because there is an error, the exception is not the error, it's just the messenger.