# Why method is not throwing Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

In this method i used `SessionFactory.openSession()` to get hibernate `Session` :

```
public static Session getSession() {
    Session session = null;
    if (factory == null) {
        session = initSessionFactory().openSession(); //initSessionFactory() returns SessionFactory object.
    } else {
        session = factory.openSession();
    }
    return session;
}
```

since, the method [`SessionFactory#openSession()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#openSession%28%29) throws `HibernateException`, then why doesn't my method throw an Exception, why there is not any CompileTime Error?

Comment: You use openSession to get a Session? I use openSession to **open** a Session! And i use **getSession** to get a Session. (your factory is always `null`?) ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `HibernateException` is RuntimeException just like `NullPointerException`

Inheritance hierarchy is

`RuntimeException` -> `NestedRuntimeException` -> `HibernateException`

Answer (score 4):

[`HibernateException` extends `RuntimeException`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html).

Answer (score 0):

`HibernateException` inherits from `RuntimeException`. You don't have to catch or declare `RuntimeExceptions`.

See [RuntimeExceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html?is-external=true)

Answer (score 0):

HibernateException extends RuntimeException, therefore making it an **unchecked** exception.

[Unchecked exceptions don't need to be caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750638/why-we-dont-have-to-add-try-catch-to-a-runtimeexception)